# Paypal Recurring Gem - Multiple Items Subscribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, recurring

I am using Paypal recurring gem with rails 3.

I have three type of subscribe packages with some add on packages so that user are able to subscribe with some add on features.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAMys.png

Refer paypal recurring gem, I cannot find Paypal Line items. I looked at the code on Github but I not sure how to modify the source code.

```
options = options.reverse_merge(
        token: @subscription.paypal_payment_token,
        description: @subscription.package_plan.description,
        payer_id: @subscription.paypal_customer_token,
        frequency: @subscription.package_plan.recurring_frequency,
        item_name: @subscription.package_plan.name,
        item_quantity: 1,
        item_amount: @subscription.package_plan.price * @subscription.package_plan.recurring_frequency,
        item_name: @subscription.package_add_ons.first.name,
        item_quantity: 1,
        item_amount: @subscription.package_add_ons.first.price * @subscription.package_plan.recurring_frequency,
        amount: @subscription.package_plan.price * @subscription.package_plan.recurring_frequency,
        currency: @subscription.package_plan.currency
    )
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uRo1.png